# Close other divs when new one opened with jQuery fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got three buttons in line with one another and when clicked, they expand a form below.

When a form has already been expanded however, clicking on one of the other buttons, does not collapse the previous form (it just expands that form above the previous).

The below code is the markup currently in place to handle this but I'm unsure on how to extend fadeToggle to collapse other forms each time a button is clicked.

I'll await answers but I'm guessing I'm going to need to add a class to the divs that contain the forms so that we can trigger a close event on click?

```
<section class="cta-buttons">
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#callback").click(function () {jQuery("#callback-form").fadeToggle();});});</script>
    <div id="callback"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Request Callback', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>

    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#enquiry").click(function () {jQuery("#enquiry-form").fadeToggle();});});</script>
    <div id="enquiry"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Make Enquiry', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>

    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#booknow").click(function () {jQuery("#booknow-form").fadeToggle();});});</script>
    <div id="booknow"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Book Now', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>

    <?php // FORMS TRIGGERED ON CLICK ?>
    <div id="callback-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=1' ); ?></div>
    <div id="enquiry-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=2' ); ?></div>
    <div id="booknow-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=3' ); ?></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `class` attributes to group common elements, and DOM traversal within the functions bound to them to create common logic and adhere to DRY principles. With that in mind, try this:

```
<section class="cta-buttons">
    <div id="callback" class="trigger" data-rel="#callback-form"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Request Callback', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>
    <div id="enquiry" class="trigger" data-rel="#enquiry-form"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Make Enquiry', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>
    <div id="booknow" class="trigger" data-rel="#booknow-form"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Book Now', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>

    <?php // FORMS TRIGGERED ON CLICK ?>
    <div id="callback-form" class="form-container"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=1' ); ?></div>
    <div id="enquiry-form" class="form-container"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=2' ); ?></div>
    <div id="booknow-form" class="form-container"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=3' ); ?></div>
</section>
```

```css
.form-container {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $('.form-container').fadeOut();
        $($(this).data('rel')).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

To stop the currently shown form, fading out and in again try this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    var currentId = '#' + $('.form-container:visible').prop('id');
    var newId = $(this).data('rel');
    $('.form-container').fadeOut();
    if (currentId != newId) {
        $(newId).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JAvG/2/)

Comment: This looks much cleaner actually. Makes sense. Thanks. With your suggestion though, it is not possible to collapse a form again so once any of the buttons is clicked, a form will remain permanently open until the page is reloaded.

Comment: That is possible, you just need to check if the visible `container-form` has the same `id` as `data('rel')`

Comment: Is this along the right lines? `$(.container-form).is(":visible")` Please could you advise of how to check if this visible div has the same id as `data('rel')`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I meant so that when you click a button and the form expands, clicking on the same button again will collapse the form. As per your jsFiddle, a form is expanded all the time once a button is clicked. Sorry if that wasn't clear - thanks.

Comment: @GeoffJackson you just need to move the `fadeOut` to outside the `if` condition. Updated

Comment: That's it. That's working perfectly. Thanks. Modified Rory's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/h7H5H/7/) for the assistance of visitors to this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to all forms (for example ".formHidden").

Then, each time you click a form, you do

```
jQuery("#enquiry").click(function () {
    jQuery("#enquiry-form").fadeToggle();
    jQuery("#enquiry-form").removeClass("formHidden")
         .siblings().addClass("formHidden");
});
```

(this code is, of course, just for the first one. You need to replicate it on the other ones).
And, of course, you need to apply the appropriate css `display:none` to the ".formHidden" class.

---

**EDIT**:

### A much cleaner approach:

```
<section class="cta-buttons">
    <div id="callbacks">
        <div id="callback"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Request Callback', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>
        <div id="enquiry"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Make Enquiry', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>
        <div id="booknow"><span class="btn"><?php _e( 'Book Now', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span></div>
    </div>

    <div id="formcallbacks">
        <?php // FORMS TRIGGERED ON CLICK ?>
        <div id="callback-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=1' ); ?></div>
        <div id="enquiry-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=2' ); ?></div>
        <div id="booknow-form" style="display: none;"><?php vfb_pro( 'id=3' ); ?></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And then

```
jQuery("#callbacks > div").click(function () {
    jQuery("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-form").fadeIn()
         .siblings().fadeOut();
});
```

Supposing the `<form>` elements are the only children inside the parent div!

**CHECK THIS JSFIDDLE**: (http://jsfiddle.net/h7H5H/5)